# How to use 2 values in 1 mat-option in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

Is it possible to have 2 values for 1 `mat-option`.

How can i achieve this kind of code with angular material?

```
<mat-select formControlName="type">
        <mat-option [fruit,place]="mango,india">
          fruit:mango, place: india
        </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: you cant use mat-option like this. just pass an object in the [value] input of the options. something like : 
``<mat-option [value]="{ fruit: 'mango', place: 'india' }" > text </mat-option>``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have an object or an array of string to achieve this:

in case of **array of string**, the data structure would be:

```
  foods: Food[] = [
    {viewValue: ['mango','india'], value: 'Ind'},
    {viewValue: ['apple','america'], value: 'US'},
    {viewValue: ['banana','colombia'], value: 'Col'}
  ];
```

in case of **object**, the data structure would be:

```
  foodObj= [
    {viewFruit: 'mango', viewCountry: 'india', value: 'Ind'},
    {viewFruit: 'apple', viewCountry: 'america', value: 'US'},
    {viewFruit: 'banana',viewCountry: 'colombia', value: 'Col'}
  ];
```

relevant **HTML**:

```
<h4>Basic mat-select (as string array)</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food (as string array)</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      fruit:{{food.viewValue[0]}}, place: {{food.viewValue[1]}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>


<h4>Basic mat-select (as object)</h4>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Favorite food (as object)</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foodObj" [value]="food.value">
      fruit:{{food.viewFruit}}, place: {{food.viewCountry}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

export interface Food {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string[];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'select-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['select-overview-example.css'],
})
export class SelectOverviewExample {
  foods: Food[] = [
    {viewValue: ['mango','india'], value: 'Ind'},
    {viewValue: ['apple','america'], value: 'US'},
    {viewValue: ['banana','colombia'], value: 'Col'}
  ];

  foodObj= [
    {viewFruit: 'mango', viewCountry: 'india', value: 'Ind'},
    {viewFruit: 'apple', viewCountry: 'america', value: 'US'},
    {viewFruit: 'banana',viewCountry: 'colombia', value: 'Col'}
  ];

}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k3qswm)